# KarateDSL can't persist my auth token on ore than one request

Tags: karate

Following on from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159904/karatedsl-parsing-a-value-from-a-response-and-adding-to-next-scenario-payload-no/52162887#52162887)

Really trying to get my head around all the documentation and I'm really struggling to get my head around a few concepts. Mainly, I don't get how the setting of headers works. In a nutshell, I do a post request to sign in and get an auth token. When i get the auth token I also want to get all the cookies and then my other tests can start. I think i'm really struggling with the idea of using the headers.js example. I tried and got no where.

my karate-config:

```
function() {
karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
karate.configure('ssl', true);
karate.configure('logPrettyRequest', true);
karate.configure('logPrettyResponse', true);

var env = karate.env; // get system property 'karate.env'
karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);

if (!env) {
   env = 'dev';
   }

var config = {
    env: env,
    baseUrl: 'https://someurl'
    }

if (env == 'dev') {
    // cust
} else if (env == 'e2e') {
    // customize
}

return config;
}
```

My authenticate feature (that sits next karate-config.js). Should session and token below be accessible in my scenarios?

```
Feature: Log in user and authenticate

Background:
* url baseUrl

Scenario: Login user

Given path '/api.fs/ProfileLogin'
And request {"request":{"LoginName":"user","Password":"password"}}
When method POST
Then status 200
And match response.IsSuccess == true
* def r = response
* def session = {"OrganizationCode":'#(r.Session.OrganizationCode)',"OrganizationId":'#(r.Session.OrganizationId)',"SessionId":"","UserId":'#(r.UserId)',"Environment":'#(r.Session.Environment)'}
* def token = r.Token
```

The following is my first proper test which after the auth above should make 2 requests.

```
Feature: Do some application stuff

Background:
* url baseUrl
* def signIn = call read('classpath:authenticate.feature')
* header Authorization = signIn.Token 

Scenario: Get an application's data and edit

# get all user's applications
Given path '/ListApplications'
And request {"request":{},"Session":'#(signIn.session)'}
When method POST
Then status 200
And def applicationId = response.Applications[0].Id

#get first application in list
Given path '/GetApplication'
And request {"request":{"ApplicationId":'#(applicationId)'},"Session":'#(signIn.session)'}
When method POST
Then status 200
```

The first request is fine, but the second request doesn't include the authToken so it fails. why isn't the auth token persisting? I tried to move the '* header Authorization = signIn.Token' into the authenticate.feature but that just meant the first request didn't contain an Authorization header.

I feel like i've tried every possibility in the tutorial, where/how after the authenticate.feature is run do I get the token and then automatically assign it to all future requests whether that be in the same scenario or another scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of
`* header Authorization = signIn.token`,

which only sets the header for the next call, you should use

`* configure headers = { Authorization: '#(signIn.token)' }`,

which sets the header for all following calls in the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as far as I can tell `signIn.session` should work. Really not able to figure out from here.

Can you try to get everything working in one scenario to begin with.

No wait, I think a simple typo could be the problem. The `t` below should be lower-case, because that's what you `def`-ed in the `authenticate.feature`

```
* header Authorization = signIn.token
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, i did actually use the lower case t in the end and i still have to set the auth header with every request. I'm ok with that for now so will park it.

Comment: I did run into another issue whereby I can only run my tests in maven if I directly reference my feature files. I have the exact same file structure as mentioned in the help files and i run mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@ignore" -Dtest=MyAppTest. And maven can't find any feature files. It does work if i change MyAppTest to the features in sub folders. Again it's probably something you can't help with actually seeing my project. That aside I'm really impressed with this framework. Great tool!

Comment: @SimonN thanks ! I'd really like to make the experience better so if you find time, try submit a working example of issues you face using the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - you could use some online oauth example perhaps. or try using karate mocks if you are adventurous